# SQL Query to Select class and frequency for Grafana Histogram

Tags: sql, mariadb, grafana

I created an query to transform data from two tables to create an histogram in Grafana.

I have the table data with the column resistance (entry for example 0.000564), and I have the table classes_resistance with the column value_class (entry from 0.32, 0.33, 0.34 to 0.61)

Query:

```
SELECT
  C.value_class AS Klasse,
  COUNT(data.resistance) AS Anzahl,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    data.resistance
    ORDER BY
      data.resistance
  ) AS Resistance_Values
FROM
  classes_resistance C
  LEFT JOIN data ON data.resistance > 0.0002
  AND data.resistance * 1000 > (
    SELECT
      IFNULL(MAX(value_class), 0)
    FROM
      classes_resistance
    WHERE
      value_class < C.value_class
  )
  AND (
    CONVERT_TZ(data.timestamp, '+00:00', '-01:00') BETWEEN $__timeFrom()
    AND $__timeTo()
    AND (
      data.resistance * 1000 < (
        SELECT
          MIN(value_class)
        FROM
          classes_resistance
        WHERE
          value_class > C.value_class
      )
      OR (
        SELECT
          MIN(value_class)
        FROM
          classes_resistance
        WHERE
          value_class > C.value_class
      ) IS NULL
      OR (
        data.resistance * 1000 > (
          SELECT
            MAX(value_class)
          FROM
            classes_resistance
        )
        AND data.resistance > 0.0002
        AND C.value_class = (
          SELECT
            MAX(value_class)
          FROM
            classes_resistance
        )
      )
    )
  )
GROUP BY
  C.value_class
ORDER BY
  C.value_class;
```

It works good in the first view, but when I check the counts of each class, there are way to many values (about 2x)

Can anybody help?

tyvm

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. This could do with a good dose of window functions https://dbfiddle.uk/1fMKE60M